# How to enable WebVR on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flags, webvr

I am trying to create a WebVR scene. For this task, I want to enable WebVR on Google Chrome. My OS is Windows 8.

I open flags using `chrome://flags/`. WebVR is not there. How can I enable it?

Comment: For Chrome 70 you can find it in `chrome://flags/`. The flag is called WebVR.

Answer (score 4):

<del>Official channels of Google Chrome do not support WebVR.</del> (now they do, see below)

There is an [unofficial build of chrome](https://webvr.info/get-chrome/) that does. FYI [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) also supports WebVR in their official and current release, as does [Samsung Internet Beta for GearVR](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000270L) (the latter after some configuration).

UPDATE: Chrome Android now works with WebVR if you enable `chrome://flags/#enable-webvr`. See [this manual on how to enable WebVR on different browsers](https://github.com/Bivrost/360WebPlayer#virtual-reality-on-desktop-and-mobile-with-webvr).

Comment: I install Firefox Nightly and add web-vr to firefox from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-webvr-enabler/. When I open an sample web-vr example, I get " Your browser supports WebVR but not the latest version.". Examples doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, firefox doesn't support the latest webvr version - but it supports webvr. Simply try examples that do not require the latest, for example the [THREE.js cubes WebVR demo](http://threejs.org/examples/webvr_cubes.html). Oh and the extension is not needed, you can go to `about:config` and change `dom.vr.cardboard.enabled` to `true` and `dom.vr.add-test-devices` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Google Chrome extension for WebVR debugging](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webvr-api-emulation/gbdnpaebafagioggnhkacnaaahpiefil)
It can really help to debug your VR application. 
You will be able change the position of the virtual device in the environment, to see the change of camera position.
Also, it is possible to emulate the HTC Vive controllers.

Alternative is to use [WebVR polyfill](https://webvr.info/)
It adds WebVR-API to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can test your sample webVR code on the following browsers :

Google Chromium
 Firefox Nightly
 Samsung browser for webVR

Google Chrome version 54.0 onwards was expected to support webVR, but it seems we have to wait a little more.

If you are not very comfortable with ThreeJS library for VR projects, you should try aframe framework ( check http://aframe.io ). Here you will focus only on the VR code flow and all other graphics related overheads (camera, rendering etc) will be taken care by aframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you still need this special Chromium build?**
In latest Chrome #58 it seems the feature is available within **chrome://flags** now

```
WebVR Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android Enabling this option
allows web applications to access experimental Virtual Reality APIs.
#enable-webvr
```

Didnt try it out yet though *(dont want to break my productive browser)*

Greetz

Comment: Unfortunately, those don't work right now (Chrome 58). There is development work going into it, but it's not ready yet.