# Get WebVR working with Chrome on Samsung S8

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr, webvr

I found many websites that suggests WebVR works on Chrome since version 56. I have Chrome v.62 working on a Samsung S8 (I even tried Chrome Canary which v65) and when I execute the simple sample code like this is one for instance:

https://github.com/mdn/webvr-tests/blob/master/basic-display-info/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>VRStageParameters basic test</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>VRStageParameters basic test</h1>

    <p id='toto'></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    var info = document.getElementById('toto');
    var vrDisplay;
    if(navigator.getVRDisplays) {
        reportStageParams();
    } else {
      info.innerHTML = 'WebVR API not supported by this browser.'
    }
    function reportStageParams() {
      info.innerHTML = 'IS WORKING SOMEHOW'
      navigator.getVRDisplays().then(function(displays) {
        vrDisplay = displays[0];
        var stageParams = vrDisplay.stageParameters;
        // stageParams is a VRStageParameters object
        if(stageParams === null) {
          info.textContent = 'Your VR Hardware does not support room-scale experiences.'
        } else {
          info.innerHTML = '<strong>Display stage parameters</strong>'
                       + '<br>Sitting to standing transform: ' + stageParams.sittingToStandingTransform
                       + '<br>Play area width (m): ' + stageParams.sizeX
                       + '<br>Play area depth (m): ' + stageParams.sizeY
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

I keep getting the message `WebVR API not supported by this browser.`?? I don't understand why. Can someone with experience setting up WebVR please tell me what I need to do in order to make it work? I use a recent phone, the latest version of the browser, so it almost seems like I need to activate WebVR somewhere in some settings but can't find anything on the web.

Comment: S8 had problems with Unity (now it seem fixed). Could it be related? https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/771

Answer (score 2):

In fact this question was asked and already answers (to some extent):

[How to enable WebVR on Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920050/how-to-enable-webvr-on-google-chrome)

Strangely, this is really the first step in getting WebVR working and it's not explained in most tutorials and official websites on WebVR... so here is:

You need to go to chrome://flags

and then scroll down until you find WebVR specific features and enable the ones you want.